# Not able display Cards in CardView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-cardview

I have written code to make a card View and created a Recycler View and Card View layout and made custom adapter class but on the main screen cards are not displaying

This is my adapter class 
BankAdapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.vikas.financemanager.R;
import com.example.vikas.financemanager.model.Bank_details;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by vikas on 28/9/17.
 */

public class BankAccountAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BankAccountAdapter.BankAccountViewHolder> {



    private List<Bank_details> bank_details;
    private Context mContext;

    public BankAccountAdapter(Context mContext,List<Bank_details> bank_details)
    {
        this.mContext= mContext;
        this.bank_details=bank_details;
    }



    @Override
    public BankAccountViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_list,parent,false);


        return new BankAccountViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(BankAccountViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Bank_details  details= bank_details.get(position);
        holder.BankName.setText(details.getBank_name());
        holder.Bank_Balance.setText(details.getBank_balance());
        holder.Account_number.setText(details.getAccount_number());
        holder.Transaction_date.setText(details.getDate_of_transaction());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }






    public class BankAccountViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


        public TextView BankName;
        public TextView Bank_Balance;
        public TextView Transaction_date;
        public TextView Account_number;
        public TextView Title;


        public BankAccountViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            BankName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.BankName);
            Bank_Balance = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bank_balance);
            Transaction_date = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.transaction_date);
            Account_number = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.account_number);
            Title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
        </LinearLayout>



        <include
            android:id="@+id/cardList"
            layout="@layout/card_recycle_view" />

        <!-- <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_body"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />-->
    </LinearLayout>







    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:name="com.example.vikas.financemanager.activity.FragmentDrawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_nav_drawer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_nav_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is my Card_list.xml

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Account Summary"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="14dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/BankName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/title"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="UCO BANK"
                android:textSize="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/account_number"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/BankName"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="**1032"
                android:textSize="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bank_balance"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/BankName"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Rs 20000"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/transaction_date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/bank_balance"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="12/10/1996"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</ScrollView>
```

and this is my main activity

```
package com.example.vikas.financemanager.activity;

import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import com.example.vikas.financemanager.R;
import com.example.vikas.financemanager.adapter.BankAccountAdapter;
import com.example.vikas.financemanager.model.Bank_details;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;
    private RecyclerView recList;
    private BankAccountAdapter adapter;
    private LinearLayoutManager llm;
    List<Bank_details> details = new ArrayList<Bank_details>();
    private String TAG=MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

       // mToolbar.setTitleTextColor(0xFFFFF);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("DashBoard");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        details = new ArrayList<>();
        recList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.cardList);



        llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recList.setLayoutManager(llm);



        adapter = new BankAccountAdapter(getApplicationContext(),details);
        bank_details();

        recList.setAdapter(adapter);




        drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
        drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);
    }




    private void bank_details() {

        Bank_details di = new Bank_details("UCO BANK","**1032","Rs 2000","12/10/1996");
        details.add(di);

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        Log.e(TAG,"size "+ details.size());

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {

    }
}
```

According to me I think I have done everything correct but I am not able to understand why cards are not being able to display. Please help me

Answer (score 1):

I got my mistake I was returning 0 in getItemCount method in Adapter class instead of details.size().